# Outer Product of Block Matrices (?)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure I'm asking the question correctly, but it's bugging me too much to let it go.

On this answer to a [prior post by me](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1918589/152225) I got stuck in what initially seemed to correspond to a dot product of vectors, and turned out to be a different operation.

My knowledge of linear algebra makes me understand a covariance matrix (as a prototypical case of symmetric semidefinite matrices, or $\bf A^\top A$ forms on my prior post) as a long list of returns for different stock ticker symbols on many days (as an example), each one representing a vector that after being scaled, and dotted with itself and the other stock company returns in the portfolio, is properly placed in a symmetric structure where the variances are in the diagonal, and covariances are off-diagonal.

Now, the operation in the answer is making reference to block matrices, with each element, $a_i$, corresponding to a row vector of norm $1$, such that

\begin{align}
A^\top A & = \begin{bmatrix}  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
                   a_1^\top    & a_2^\top    &  a_3^\top   & \cdots & a_n^\top\\
                   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\end{bmatrix}
          \begin{bmatrix}
                   \cdots & a_1 & \cdots\\
                   \cdots & a_2 & \cdots \\
                   \cdots & a_3 & \cdots \\
                   & \vdots&\\
                    \cdots & a_n & \cdots
             \end{bmatrix}\\
            &= a_1^\top a_1 + a_2^\top a_2 + a_3^\top a_3 + \cdots+a_n^\top a_n.
\end{align}

I don't understand how this outer product (??) would work out to end up with the sum of outer products of vectors of identical indexes.

I know that an **example** (much like debugging a loop function) would clarify the overall structure of the resulting matrix and the operations involved. Alternatively, even **the name of the operation** possibly with a link or reference would be good.

Please note that the author explicitly clarifies in the comments, "I'm no longer saying they are orthogonal [the $a_i$ column vectors], only that the projections are orthogonal."

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication. It may also help you to explicitly write down the size of the matrices involved (ie how many rows and columns does $a_i$ have? $a_i^T$? $a_i^Ta_i$?)

Comment: @stewbasic Thank you. Do you want to write something so I can approve it? I checked the link, and now it's clear.

Comment: If $A$ has more rows than columns and the columns are linearly independent, then $A^\top A$ is invertible, and (1) $B = (A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top$ is a left inverse of $A$, in that $BA$ is an identity matrix (which has only as many rows or columns as $A$ has columns) and (2) $AB$ is a symmetric singular matrix that projects onto the column space of $A$, i.e. if $x$ is a column as big as those of $A$ then $ABx = \begin{cases} x & \text{if $x$ is in the column space of $A$}, \\ 0 & \text{if $x$ is orthogonal to the column space}. \end{cases}$ $\qquad$